# Passing Authentication Credentials From Webapplication A to Webapplication B?

Tags: php

I have got a Web application say A which via url needs to communicate with application B and get the response from B. Application B uses a HTTP authentication mechanism. What I need to do is pass the authentication credentials from Application A to Application B through url request. I dont want to use _GET or _POST method due to security issues

Comment: this might help http://imar.spaanjaars.com/363/how-do-i-pass-credentials-to-a-web-service-that-uses-basic-authentication

Comment: @Marc I don't think a .NET tutorial is applicable here.

Comment: That's true Dan, think I linked the wrong one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an encrypted string to the URL request from A to B.
B should know the decryption method and parameters, it decrypt the encrypted string which received from A and check it is correct or not.

Comment: thanks, I am going to use single sign on which uses some what same concept.